# Annoying suggested edits indicator

Tags: support, status-completed

Since I reached 1k I have an annoying all-time present suggested edits indicator stuck at 8.

[image]

It's stuck at eight. At first I thought it might be the problem about my own edits being shown. ( [Number of suggested edits seems to include own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109630) ) However, it did neither resolve itself with another actual edit I did since reaching 1k like it was when I reached 750 and opened up tag wikis. Moreover, 1k didn't give me any additional edit queues.

I have tried the usual culprits and opened the site with full reloads, cleared my cache and switched to incognito mode. When there are actual suggested edits it seems to start at eight, showing nine or more. If I clear my queue, I go down to eight again. It still works normally on ELU.SE.

Comment: Did you "skip" any review tasks? Those things stay on your counter even if the review queues show zero. They only vanish once that particular item is handled by other users (which could take some time with a small number of high rep users).

Comment: @Ghanima History doesn't show any skipped ones

Comment: For future reference, with [the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/333472) on stackexchange, this issue is effectively no longer existent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that you have the [“moderator tools” a.k.a. “10k” privilege](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (1000 rep in private beta, 2000 in public beta, 10,000 (hence the nickname) on graduated sites such as ELU), the indicator shows the total number of pending reviews, not just the number of pending suggested edits.

Furthermore the suggested edit count deducts the edits that you've already reviewed, but the total review count does not even attempt to deduct the reviews that you aren't eligible for. That was deemed too expensive for the database. So the number you get is an overapproximation and is often uselessly wrong.

There have been numerous complaints and suggestions of improvements over the years. See [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it), [Wrong posts number on Review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section), [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many), …

Comment: So this will go down when we have a reviewer base that clears the overall review queues?

Comment: @Helmar Having more reviewers will help, but it won't make the numbers really informative. On a large site, the number is pretty much always nonzero because there's always something new to review.

Comment: So I guess the magic words are: *get used to it*?